# How can I code this in recursive algorithm (python)?

Tags: python, recursion

I want to code this algorithm so that I can choose the number of the b's (b1, b2, b3, ..., bn) and what they add up to a specific number like 100.
I tried coding them with recursive algorithm but none of them seems to work.
I have tried something like this -> def permu_weights(temp, num, metric, maximum).

```py
b= []
for b1 in range(1, 100):
    for b2 in range(1, 100-b1):
        for b3 in range(1, 100-b1-b2):
            b4 = 100-b1-b2-b3
            b.append([b1/100, b2/100, b3/100, b4/100])
```

```py
#this doesn't work...
b = []
def permu_weights(temp, num, metric, up):
    for i in range(1,up):
        temp.append(i)

        if len(temp) < num-1:
            permu_weights(temp, num, metric, up=metric-sum(temp))     

        elif len(temp) == num-1:
            temp.append(metric-sum(temp))
            b.append(temp)
            temp = temp[:-2]

    return b

permu_weights([],3,10,10)
```

Comment: *Why* would you want this to be recursive? Seems perfectly good as is.

Comment: show your recursive version.

Comment: I want to code so that I can specify how much they add up to and the number of b's which is not so interchangeable for that code.

Comment: keep `b1...bn` as list, not separated values. And use this list as argument in function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This recursive function yields the elements of b, for an identical result:

```
def weights(n, remaining_parts, total_parts):
    if n == 1:
        yield [remaining_parts / total_parts]
    else:
        for i in range(1, remaining_parts):
            for tail in weights(n-1, remaining_parts-i, total_parts):
                yield [i / total_parts] + tail

c = list(weights(4, 100, 100))
```

Note that this breaks horribly if you pass it wrong starting values, like `weights(0, 1, 2)`. You could wrap it in an outer function that checks some assertions:

```
def generate_weights(n, parts):
    assert parts > n > 0 and isinstance(n, int) and isinstance(parts, int)
    yield from weights(m, parts, parts)

# safer
d = list(generate_weights(4, 100))
```

Comment: You are a genius. Thank you. But have to change the first line after else
`for i in range(1, remaining_parts):`

Comment: You're right, that was a leftover from my first draft - with remaining_parts there, the subtraction was no longer needed, fixed.